# Show current location in Cesium

Tags: cesiumjs

I'm using cesium map

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Draw</title>
  <script src="../../Cesium/Cesium.js"></script>
  <style>
    @import url(../../Cesium/Widgets/widgets.css);
    html, body, #cesiumContainer {
        width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: hidden;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cesiumContainer"></div>
  <script>
    Cesium.BingMapsApi.defaultKey = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
  var viewer = new Cesium.Viewer('cesiumContainer', {infoBox : false, selectionIndicator : false });
  var color;
  var camera = viewer.camera;
  var polyline;
  var drawing = false;
  var positions = [];
  var handler = new Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventHandler(viewer.canvas);
  handler.setInputAction(
      function (click) {
          if (drawing) {
              color.alpha = 0.6;
              viewer.entities.add({
                  polygon: {
                      hierarchy : {
                          positions : positions
                      },
                      material : color,
                      outline : true
                  }
              });
              viewer.entities.remove(polyline);
              positions = [];
          } else {
              color = Cesium.Color.fromRandom({alpha : 1.0});
              polyline = viewer.entities.add({
                  polyline : {
                    positions : new Cesium.CallbackProperty(function(){
                      return positions;
                    }, false),
                    material : color
                  }
              });
          }
          drawing = !drawing;
      },
      Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.LEFT_CLICK
  );

  handler.setInputAction(
      function (movement) {
          var surfacePosition = camera.pickEllipsoid(movement.endPosition);
          if (drawing && Cesium.defined(surfacePosition)) {
              positions.push(surfacePosition);
          }
      },
      Cesium.ScreenSpaceEventType.MOUSE_MOVE
  );
  
  camera.flyTo({destination: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-100, 40, 10000)});

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to show current location on the map and it should zoom that location from where the user is accessing the map. Is it possible in cesium, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possible.
Here is a [Sandcastle link](https://sandcastle.cesium.com/#c=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).

Answer (score 0):

check cesium api doc here.

https://cesium.com/learn/cesiumjs/ref-doc/Viewer.html?classFilter=viewer#zoomTo

```
viewer.zoomTo(any entity object you want to focus, option)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).